# Do SAM turrets add streak points?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

In modern warfare 3 you can now earn streak points for taking out enemy aircraft. Does the aircraft a SAM turret takes out count for streaks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they do not.

I believe using kill streak weapons like using the predator missile to kill another player, does count towards another kill streak, but I don't think that SAM turret aircraft kills do.

Comment: If you look in the lower right corner of the screen, there is an icon representing each killstreak reward you have turned on. Next to that are a series of lines - each is filled in when you get a point toward a killstreak. If a SAM turret gets a kill, a line isn't filled in, so it doesn't count toward your next killstreak.

Comment: What if you shoot down an aircraft using a predator missile?

Answer (score 1):

The SAM Turret is used for clearing the skies of enemy killstreaks, it does not add to your pointstreak. Using it does give you XP though and after calling in a certain amount of SAM Turrets you complete the challenge "Keeping Em' Down".